# AWS API Gateway same endpoint locked and unlocked

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have an endpoint in ApiGateway of the form `GET /user/{userId}` and I want the endpoint to be open (i.e. without any security) and return some basic non-sensitive information about a user (e.g. nickname). But I also want that when a user is authenticated and authorized (through Cognito) to show more information about that user. Is there a way to set up this in CloudFormation?

My code so far:

```
 /person/{id}:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${MyFunctionArn.Arn}/invocations
        httpMethod: POST
        type: "AWS_PROXY"
      tags:
        - Person
      summary: Find person by identifier
      description: Returns a single person matching id parameter
      operationId: GetPersonById
      security:
        - CognitoUserPool: [ ]
        - <what_can_I_put_here_for_an_open_endpoint?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved in a couple of ways. However, IMHO, the best way to
implement this is to use an **Authorizer** accessible from the API Gateway >> API >> Authorizers:

[image]

You can configure a Lambda to implement the authorization logic for you and mention the details of the same in the above section ([Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/configure-api-gateway-lambda-authorization-with-console.html)). The same "Authorizer Lambda" should be configured to address the required authorization-failure logic i.e. *return some basic non-sensitive information about a user (e.g. nickname)* (sic).

The created Authorizer can be attached to any of the API Gateway routes. In order to do so, navigate to the Route >> Method (GET, PUT, DELETE, etc) >> Method Request >> Authorization >> Choose the configured Authorizer. The authorizer forwards the request to the respective API, only in case of successful validation from the **Authorizer**, where you can serve the logic for your use case i.e. *when a user is authenticated and authorized (through Cognito) to show more information about that user* (sic).